# Оптимизация многостраничных элементов

Tags: asp.net

На странице `.aspx` есть элемент [Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fs0za4w6.aspx). Каждая из страниц, помещенных в него оформлена в виде пользовательского элемента `.ascx` и этих страниц много. При отладке заметил, что при загрузке самого `wizard`, вместе с ним загружаются *все* его страницы, в том числе невидимые.
Нельзя ли загружать только видимую страницу?
Может есть по-лучше способы реализации многостраничных элементов?
Что быстрее работает, меньше ресурсов требует [MultiView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview.aspx) или `Wizard`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Особой разницы между двумя этими контролами фактически нет. `Wizard` более кастомизируемый контрол, позволяющий отобразить прогрессбар. В то время, как  `MultiView` требует его самостоятельной разработки.

Относительно вашего вопроса о произовдительности. Оба эти конторла во время отработки цикла страницы динамически подгружают все свои дочерние элементы. Таким образом во время дебага вы видите все дочерние элементы и, соответственно, все ваши `UserControl'ы` так же проходят полный цикл загрузки (`Init`, `Load` и т.д.). Однако при возвращении страницы сервером клиенту (браузеру), в html-разметке будет срендерен только один из шагов вашего `Wizard`.

Если постоянная загрузка ваших контролов значительно влиятет на производительность, то разумнее их добавлять на страницу динамически, а не статически ложить в `Wizard` или `MultiView`, а после фактически их прятать.